# How to setup SLI on two GTX 560Ti's

Tags: windows, gpu, driver, nvidia, sli

I can't find any setting in Nvidia control panel, both cards are installed correctly with the SLI link plugged in. I read something which indicated Nvidia have removed the option for SLI. Is there some way for me to enable it, such as rolling back drivers, or turning it on some other way?